# ios:how to run html data in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json

Hi Friends my project is based on parsing datas from `JSON`, I have done well in parsing datas now my problem is. `In one of my module i received some html data from json. Now i need to display in screen by running that html.` Is it possible in ios if it possible Please help me how to do it. i have no idea regarding this
Here is the JSON file i received

But its not worked. I need to run that html and have to diaplay in textview pls help me how to do it
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the content you get is HTML so instead of UITextView use a UIWebView and then use loadHTMLString with it.

```
///load
//tweet = [[NSDictionary alloc]init]; uneeded
id tweet = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
id items = tweet[@"aboutUsContent"];

//get html
NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString string];
for(NSDictionary *item in items) {//it is just one item in your example but ill write the code so it does handle N items
    id desc1 = [item  valueForKey:@"content"];
    [html appendString:desc1];
}

 //now set it
 [AboutWebView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];
```

Comment: disclaimer: written inline but thats basically it

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. is it possible to add text color in uiwebview content

Comment: sure, you can use ANY html tags available with UIWebView. what do you wanna do?

Answer (score 1):

you can take your data into  a NSSTRING and load it like this :

```
 [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```